# Small samples: test for uniform distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, clustering, uniform-distribution

I have ~500 of (experimental) samples of data from a range [0,1], and I would like to see if the overall distribution is uniform or whether there is some clustering going on. I would have used Chi-Squared test as recommended here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions), but there are two problems

1. Each sample is small (3-10 datapoints), which is probably too small for a Chi-squared test
2. The particular interval in which clustering may occur varies, e.g. for one samples it may be at ~0.2 and for another at ~0.5 etc
3. I see some clustering using visualisations, but there is a small number of outliers so I can't rescale each sample based on the value of the first datapoint.

Is there a statistical test / some other approach that I could use?

Comment: If you have a particular alternative model in mind, then fit the two and compare loglikelihoods.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks! The problem is I don't! I just expect that there'll be some clustering. Also even if I try something like Normal, do you think that I can get results with 3-10 points per sample?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't combine all your samples into one big sample?  The range is the same for all of them, so...

Comment: @jbowman Unfortunately, no, as I suspect that the interval where clustering occurs is different for each sample (point 2 in the question), so I'm afraid that if I combine everything together, any clustering will be evened out.

Comment: you could calculate the correlations with order statistics and the expected order statistics from a uniform sample same size, and find p-values by simulation. Then plot the p-values (which should be uniform if all he nulls are true).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you very much! Sorry, my stats isn't that good, could you please explain this a little more? In particular, I don't see how order statistics apply to this case?

Answer (score 1):

At just 3-10 samples, you can't reliably "prove" clustering.

Unless (maybe) you get the almost exact same value every time, the test *should* not reject the null hypothesis, simply because of your tiny sample size. The chance of the second and third values being 0.1 close to the first is >10% each. So in >1% of cases, you will see three values within 0.1 - a naive user would call this a "cluster", but it is not statistically significant. In particular, if you have >500 data sets like this, you *need* to correct for multiple testing, so you don't get false discoveries.